# PhpStorm - wrong syntax highlighting with Blade

Tags: laravel, syntax-highlighting, phpstorm, laravel-blade

When I create a Blade template in PhpStorm, for example *login.blade.php*, syntax highlighting works correctly. But when I name it *layout.blade.php*, it doesn't. Why? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have now a file called layout.blade.php.php?

Comment: Please show a screenshot of whole IDE (including editor tab) with that file opened.

Comment: P.S. You better write some comment starting with `@username` after making updates otherwise person who asked for it may not be aware of them .. and not everyone is re-checking existing tickets for *possible* updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | File Types`
2. `Text files`
3. Find and get rid of unwanted pattern (most likely will something be similar to `layout.blade` or alike.